# Can't bind 'tap' event to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

Trying to tap on canvas and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong please?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>canvas tap</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#my_canvas').bind('tap', function() {
            alert("Canvas pressed!");
        });
    });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" style="width:auto;height:auto;background-color:yellow">
    <canvas id="#my_canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a "tap" event in (standard) jQuery? I don't think so ... I would try to go with "click" instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tap` event is defined by [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) while you only included the plain jQuery.